# embeded slide hover not working

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

jquery toggle function

```
$('.thumbnail').hover(function () {
        $('#Tools', this).slideToggle(1000);
    });
```

the building function Onsuccess

```
        function OnSuccess(response) {
        var FileData = JSON.parse(response);
        for (i = 0; i < FileData.length; i++) {
            $("#Row").append('<div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6" id ="'+FileData[i].ID+'">'
                   + '<a title="' + FileData[i].Name + '" href="#">'
                   + '<img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src=' + FileData[i].Path + '>'
                   + '</a>'
                    + '<div class="container" id="Tools">'
           +'<nav id="nav__menu_icons">'
                +'<ul>'
                    +'<li >'
                        +'<i class="fa fa-cloud-download" aria-hidden="true"></i>'

                +'  </li>'
                    +'<li>'
                    +'<i class="fa fa-cloud-upload" aria-hidden="true"></i>'


                +'  </li>'
                    +'<li >'
                +'<i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>'
                +'<li>'
           +'  <section title=".squaredThree">'

       +' <div class="squaredThree">'
        + ' <input type="checkbox" value="None" id="squaredThree" name="check" unchecked />'
        +'  <label for="squaredThree"></label>'
       +' </div>'

                   + '</div>')
```

html code

```
<div class="container">
      <div class="row" id="Row">

        <hr>

        <hr>
      </div>
    </div>
```

the toggle is not working everything is there when i check the html code seems like iam hovering on something else or is it the jquery need to be fixed

Comment: You gotta assign hover after you insert the html, or to use `$('body').on('hover', '.thumbnail', function () { ... })`.

Comment: the hover is insterted After in my class  i just posted it this way , is that what u mean or should i use the $('Body').on('hover','thumbnail',function(){...})

Comment: Should be just after `$("#Row").append(...)` or the way I suggested above (assign to body).

Comment: By the way, when you extend the string in new lines, just put backslash at the end of line, no need to concat strings.

Comment: Your code should like [this one](https://jsfiddle.net/ze5dxtg7/1/) at the end.